# Referencing SQL Username and Password from KeyVault in YAML

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

Below I have an Azure CI pipeline written in YAML, I already created a KV with 2 secrets (Username and Password) and their respective values (admin and password). Now, I have been trying to refer the secrets in variables into `task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` but it doesnt work.

If I put `$Username and $Password` in SqlUsername and SqlPassword, I'd get this error `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Username'.`

If I put `'$(Username)'and '$(Password)'` in SqlUsername and SqlPassword, I'd get this error `Login failed for user '***'.`

What should I put there or how do I refer them properly? Thanks!

```
trigger:
- master
 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:    
  $Username: ""
  $Password: ""

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  displayName: 'Get credentials from Key-Vault'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Test-SC'
    KeyVaultName: 'Test-KV'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: false

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Reg Database DDL Script'
  inputs:
    SqlUsername: $Username
    SqlPassword: $Password
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, so set `RunAsPreJob: true` and `SqlUsername: '$(Username)'` `SqlPassword: '$(Password)'` make sure you have access policies added and the name of the KV and azureSubscription are both correct